# Is this interpretation of prediction intervals correct?

Tags: regression, interpretation, prediction-interval

I have a regression model relating to a ''normal'' population. If a new observation which corresponds to point $x$ is outside the prediction interval at $x$, do I have a reason to suspect the new observation is not in the normal population?

Comment: @bellmaneqn "Falling out of confidence intervals of fitted values" is confusing on several levels.  Confidence intervals are not directly relevant in this setting, which is why this question refers to *prediction* intervals.

Comment: is your $x$ also random?

Answer (score -1):

A $100\times (1-\alpha )\% $ prediction interval should contain the next observation $100\times (1-\alpha )\%$ of the time. That is, it will not contain the next observation about $100\times (\alpha )\% $ of the time.

Comment: That's not the case for classical prediction intervals, because the probability is the *joint* probability of the data and the next observation.  One has to understand "of the time" to mean "when the entire data generation process, prediction interval procedure, and new observation are repeated many times."

Comment: @whuber Is generating a new prediction interval many times related to the idea of creating confidence intervals over and over that contain the true parameter $(1-\alpha)100\%$ of the time?

Comment: @Dave Kind of.  With a prediction interval, you simultaneously generate the interval and its target (which is a random variable).  The interval is intended to contain the target at least $(1-\alpha)100\%$ of the time while, in some sense (which varies with the situation), being as short as possible.